SpringBoot: @Service, @Repository, @Transactional
A bit of a newbie question about SpringBoot 3.
I am trying to set a simple application and I am having issues with the transactions, I am assuming I am doing something wrong or the design is not correct.
I have an entity
@Entity
public @Data class UserAccount {

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_account_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    @SQLJoinTableRestriction("active <> 0")
    private List<UserAccountRole> roles;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_account_authorities",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id"))
    @SQLJoinTableRestriction("active <> 0")
    private List<UserAccountAuthority> authorities;

}

I have a repository
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface UserAccountRepository extends JpaRepository<UserAccount, Long> {

    UserAccount findByUsername(String username);

}

Then I am setting up my authentication service and I am using this:
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserAccount user = userAccountRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username);
        }

        Hibernate.initialize(user.roles()); <--- HERE
        Hibernate.initialize(user.authorities());

        String[] roles = user.roles().stream().map(UserAccountRole::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = user.authorities().stream().map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.authority().toString())).toList();

        return User.withUsername(user.username())
                .password(user.password())
                .authorities(authorities)
                .roles(roles)
                .build();
    }
}

When I try to get the Lazy collection initialized I get a:
JDBC exception executing SQL [select r1_0.user_account_id,r1_1.id,r1_1.active,r1_1.role from user_account_roles r1_0 join user_account_role r1_1 on r1_1.id=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.user_account_id=? and (r1_0.active <> 0)] [ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block] [n/a]

I am assuming it's because I have something wrongly configured when it comes to transactions...
I added the @EnableTransactionManagement to the configuration but not sure if it's actually doing something.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableTransactionManagement
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    final UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

I am using a Postgres database, if that affects in anything.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Check the logs before this ERROR, some failed statement broke the transaction. See the discussion here
